# How to Write Left Outer join for this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I had a table like

```
ParsereplyId   Message   Callid   status    EMailid       subject 

------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1        hi         2222   Replied   g.m.p@m.com    Log a cll
      2        hello      2222   Replied   g.m.p@m.com    Re: 
      3        hi2        2222   New       g.m.p@m.com    Re:log a cll
      4        hello2     2223   Read      g.p@m.com      Log a cldf
      5        how r u    2223   New       g.p@m.com      Re:Log a
```

From the above table i want to get the following output:

```
ParsereplyId Message  Callid  status    EMailid       subject 

-------------------------------------------------------------------
      3      hi2       2222   New      g.m.p@m.com    Re:log a cll
      5      how r u   2223   New      g.p@m.com      Re:Log a
```

I have tried the following query.
but i would like to do it in Left outer Join

```
SELECT  A.[ParsedReplyId]
                , A.[EMailId]
                , A.[Message] 
                , A.[CallId]   
                , [UM_User].[UserName]                  
FROM IM_IncidentReplyMail AS A 
        INNER JOIN
                (SELECT  MAX(ParsedReplyId) AS parseid 
                 FROM [IM_IncidentReplyMail]  
                 GROUP BY [CallId]) AS B 
        INNER JOIN   
         [UM_User] ON [UM_User].[EmailId] = A.[EmailId] 
        WHERE 
            B.parseid = A.[ParsedReplyId]
```

how to implement above sql query to the inner join??

**Edit:** I Corrected my mistake above

UM_USer table contains `username, emailid`, based on email id from two table i can get the username of that mail.

**Edit 2:**
I can use Left outer join instead of using inner join like

```
 SELECT  A.[ParsedReplyId]
                    , A.[EMailId]
                    , A.[Message] 
                    , A.[CallId]   
                    , [UM_User].[UserName]                  
            FROM IM_IncidentReplyMail AS A 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    (SELECT  MAX(ParsedReplyId) AS parseid 
                     FROM [IM_IncidentReplyMail]  
                     GROUP BY [CallId]) AS B 
            ON 1=1
            LEFT OUTER  JOIN   
             [UM_User] ON [UM_User].[EmailId] = A.[EmailId] 
            WHERE 
                B.parseid = A.[ParsedReplyId]
```

Here I used 1=1 condition which is not the right way to use in queries. it makes my code ugly. so i am asking you help to resolve this.

Comment: You know you're missing a space between `INNER` and `JOIN` right?

Comment: give details on  tables properly ...

Comment: I am assuming this is SQL Server that you are using, correct? Do you want the record with highest ParsedReplyID for each CallID group? If so, you could do `select * from tablename a inner join (select max(parsedreplyid) as mp, callid from tablename group by callid) b on a.parsedreplyid = b.mp`

Comment: @zedfoxus: the exact output that i want is given by previous comment. Now i want to do it in left outer join.

Comment: @Gomathipriya can you please see that below query will help you for your required output

Comment: What do you want to do left join with? Can you edit your question and include the end result you are looking for after you do a left join?

Comment: Any specific reason for this **but i would like to do it in Left outer Join**

Comment: Also **TAG** the `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: @MotoGP: Yes, This is the standard that we are using in our organisation

Comment: @Gomathipriya - Your org is in wrong path. Which database you are using

Comment: @MotoGP: we are using DBMS, What is wrong in it. we are using more procedure. we are using same standard for the joins

Comment: @Gomathipriya Sql Server or Oracle or Mysql or DB2 etc.. Which one you are using

Comment: @Gomathipriya is the below Query is useful to you . when you have asked question in SO. you need to properly respond to help you further . if you are not clear on your task SO will not entertain this kind of stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the query according to your required output

```
    DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
        (Id INT, Message VARCHAR(7), Call INT, status VARCHAR(7), EMail VARCHAR(11), subject VARCHAR(12))
    ;

    INSERT INTO @Table1
        (Id, Message, Call, status, EMail, subject)
    VALUES
        (1, 'hi', 2222, 'Replied', 'g.m.p@m.com', 'Log a cll'),
        (2, 'hello', 2222, 'Replied', 'g.m.p@m.com', 'Re:'),
        (3, 'hi2', 2222, 'New', 'g.m.p@m.com', 'Re:log a cll'),
        (4, 'hello2', 2223, 'Read', 'g.p@m.com', 'Log a cldf'),
        (5, 'how r u', 2223, 'New', 'g.p@m.com', 'Re:Log a')
    ;

        SELECT T.Id,
        TT.Message,
        TT.Call,
        TT.status,
        TT.EMail,
        TT.subject 
        FROM @Table1 tt 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT Id,
        MAX(subject) OVER(PARTITION BY call ORDER BY call) subject,
        MAX(Message) OVER(PARTITION BY call ORDER BY call) Message  FROM @Table1)T
        ON T.Id = TT.Id AND T.Message = TT.Message AND T.subject = TT.subject
WHERE T.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Can't we do this with simple `ROW_NUMBER` implementation

Comment: @mohan111:  your Query is useful but i clearly said that i want to implement it in left outer join, not in inner join. Anyway sorry for not responding early.

Comment: yeah we can do in simple row_number but both will serve the same purpose because partition will be done by call column @MotoGP

Comment: why you desperately need left outer join @Gomathipriya can you please elaborate ?

Comment: This is the standard that we are using in our organisation

Comment: @Gomathipriya please see the updated query using Left outer jojn

Comment: @Gomathipriya can you please update on modified answer

Comment: @Gomathipriya - Definitely this is a OFF-TOPIC conversion so deleted all my comments. But don't to this using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @MotoGP: May i know the reason

Comment: @Gomathipriya When you have a direct train from t-nagar to tambaram. You are going to beach station from tnagar and from beach station you are coming back to Tambaram

Comment: @Gomathipriya - I replied back